# My Form data is not getting submitted or saved if body:Form is not used in flutter appplication

Tags: forms, flutter, validation

My Form data is not getting submitted or saved  if  body:Form is not used in flutter appplication.

If body:Form is used  and  not SingleChildScrollView  my total form page or Widget which consists of 12 to 13 Text Items are not visible including the 'Upload' or Submit' Button.

Here is my code

```
  body: Form(
      key: formKey,
        child: Center(
        child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
    SizedBox(height: 20,), //just for spacing
    Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,

    children: <Widget>[
    Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15)),
              Container(
                child: imageFile==null?
                FlatButton(
                    onPressed: (){
                      _showDialog();
                    },
                    child: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo,size: 80,color: Color(0xffff2fc3),)
                ):
                Image.file(imageFile,width: 200,height: 100,),
              ),

              SizedBox(height: 10,),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Theme(
                      data: ThemeData(
                        hintColor: Colors.blue,
                      ),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        validator: (value){
                          if(value.isEmpty){
                            return "Please write  a";
                          }else {
                            a = value;
                          }
                        },

                        keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                        autofocus: false,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'A',
                        
                        ),
                        maxLength: 15,


                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  ),


                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Theme(
                        data: ThemeData(
                          hintColor: Colors.blue,
                        ),

                        child: TextFormField(
                        validator: (value){
                          if(value.isEmpty){
                            return "Please write the b";
                          }else {
                            b= value;
                          }
                        },

                        keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                        autofocus: false,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'B',
                        
                        ),
                        maxLength: 15,


                        ),

                      ),
                  ),
                  ),
],
      ),




      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Theme(
                        data: ThemeData(
                          hintColor: Colors.blue,
                        ),

                      child: TextFormField(
                        validator: (value){
                          if(value.isEmpty){
                            return "Please write the C";
                          }else {
                           c = value;
                          }
                        },

                        keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                        autofocus: false,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'C',
                     
                        ),
                        maxLength: 15,


                      ),

                      ),
                    ),
                  ),



                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Theme(
                        data: ThemeData(
                          hintColor: Colors.blue,
                        ),

                        child: TextFormField(
                          validator: (value){
                            if(value.isEmpty){
                              return "Please write the D";
                            }else {
                              d = value;
                            }
                          },

                          keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                          autofocus: false,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'D',
                           
                          ),
                          maxLength: 15,


                        ),

                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
],
      ),


      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Theme(
                        data: ThemeData(
                          hintColor: Colors.blue,
                        ),

                        child: TextFormField(
                          validator: (value){
                            if(value.isEmpty){
                              return "Please write the E";
                            }else {
                              e = value;
                            }
                          },

                          keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                          autofocus: false,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'E ',
                           
                          ),
                          maxLength: 15,


                        ),

                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Theme(
                        data: ThemeData(
                          hintColor: Colors.blue,
                        ),

                        child: TextFormField(
                          validator: (value){
                            if(value.isEmpty){
                              return "Please write the F";
                            }else {
                              f = value;
                            }
                          },

                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          autofocus: false,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'F',
                      
                          ),
                          maxLength: 15,


                        ),

                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

        ],
      ),


      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Theme(
                        data: ThemeData(
                          hintColor: Colors.blue,
                        ),

                        child: TextFormField(
                          validator: (value){
                            if(value.isEmpty){
                              return "Please write the G";
                            }else {
                             g = value;
                            }
                          },

                          keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                          autofocus: false,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: ' G ',
                           
                          ),
                          maxLength: 15,


                        ),

                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                      Expanded(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Theme(
                            data: ThemeData(
                              hintColor: Colors.blue,
                            ),

                            child: TextFormField(
                              validator: (value){
                                if(value.isEmpty){
                                  return "Please write H";
                                }else {
                                  h = value;
                                }
                              },

                              keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                              autofocus: false,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: ' H  ',
                           
                              ),
                              maxLength: 15,


                            ),

                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
        ],
      ),




      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 1,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Theme(
                        data: ThemeData(
                          hintColor: Colors.blue,
                        ),

                        child: TextFormField(
                          validator: (value){
                            if(value.isEmpty){
                              return "Please write the I";
                            }else {
                              i = value;
                            }
                          },

                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          autofocus: false,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'I',
                      
                        ),
                          maxLength: 15,


                        ),

                      ),
                    ),
                  ),





                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Theme(
                        data: ThemeData(
                          hintColor: Colors.blue,
                        ),

                        child: TextFormField(
                          validator: (value){
                            if(value.isEmpty){
                              return "Please write J";
                            }else {
                              j = value;
                            }
                          },

                          keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                          autofocus: false,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: ' J ',
                         
                          ),
                          maxLength: 15,


                        ),

                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
        ],
      ),

    
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Theme(
                    data: ThemeData(
                      hintColor: Colors.blue,
                    ),

                    child: TextFormField(
                      validator: (value){
                        if(value.isEmpty){
                          return "Please write the K";
                        }else {
                          k = value;
                        }
                      },

                      keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                      autofocus: false,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: ' K ',
                   
                      ),
                      maxLength: 15,


                    ),

                  ),
                ),
              ),


                  SizedBox(width: 5,),



        ],
      ),






              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: (){

                  if(imageFile == null){
                    Fluttertoast.showToast(
                        msg: "Please select an image",
                        gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
                        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
                        timeInSecForIosWeb: 2
                    );
                  }else {
                    upload();
                  }

                },
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
                color: Color(0xffff2fc3),
                child: Text("Upload",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18,color: Colors.blue),),
              )


    ],//Widget
    ),//Column

    ],Widget

        ),//column

    ),//Center

    ),//Form
   
   
    );Scaffold
  }
```

And If I have used body:SingleChildScrollView  my form Widget is scrolling and Upload or Submit button is visible  but unable to save or store the Form  data into  firebase database.

If body:Form (   )   conatins only 5 items or less  ,everything is working fine as I am seeing 'Upload' or 'submit' Button and able to submit the form data.

Please fix my issue.

Error: when scrollview is used and clicked on submitor upload  button

E/flutter (29120): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'validate' was called on null.
E/flutter (29120): Receiver: null
E/flutter (29120): Tried calling: validate()
E/flutter (29120): #0      _UploadDataState.upload (package:scarves_store/UploadData.dart:587)
E/flutter (29120): #1      _UploadDataState.build. (package:scarves_store/UploadData.dart:519)
E/flutter (29120): #2      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:992)
E/flutter (29120): #3      _InkResponseState.build. (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1098)
E/flutter (29120): #4      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:184)
E/flutter (29120): #5      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:524)
E/flutter (29120): #6      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:301)
E/flutter (29120): #7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:256)
E/flutter (29120): #8      GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:158)
E/flutter (29120): #9      GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:224)
E/flutter (29120): #10     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:200)
E/flutter (29120): #11     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:158)
E/flutter (29120): #12     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:104)
E/flutter (29120): #13     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:88)
E/flutter (29120): #14     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1206)
E/flutter (29120): #15     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100)
E/flutter (29120): #16     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005)
E/flutter (29120): #17     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:267)
E/flutter (29120): #18     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:176)
E/flutter (29120):

Comment: Please add upload();  method

Comment: Future<void> upload() async{  if(formKey.currentState.validate()) {
    StorageReference reference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(
      "images")   .child(new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString() + "."           imageFile.path);   StorageUploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(imageFile);

Comment: var imageUrl = await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
      String url = imageUrl.toString();  DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance      .reference().child("Data");  String uploadId = databaseReference         .push() .key;   HashMap map = new HashMap();
  map ["cattegorrytype"] = cattegorrytype;      map ["a"] = a; map ["b"] = b; map ["c"] = c;map ["d"] = d;map ["e"] = e;map [["f"] = f;     map ["g"] = g;
      map ["h"] =h;  map ["j"] = j;map ["imgUrl"] = url, databaseReference.child(uploadId).set(map);    }  } }

Comment: above is my  upload(); method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try This:

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Center(
   child: Form(
    key: formKey,
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(height: 20,), //just for spacing
        .....// OTHER WIDGETS
      ],
     ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Ok Mohammed I will update you after trying your code thank you.

Comment: Thank you Mohammed , You have absolutely fixed my issue. Thanks once again. Be with me  Please also focus on my other queries on stack. How should I contact you gain if I want to communicate with you for my flutter queries?

Comment: You can reply to my stack account

Comment: ok please answer  here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65435218/my-form-data-is-not-getting-submitted-or-saved-if-bodyform-is-not-used-in-flutt/65435677?noredirect=1#comment115688438_65435677

Comment: Mohammad_Asef   please try to answer my query here   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65395772/how-to-open-or-view-the-pdf-using-download-url-after-downloading-from-firebase-s